# RPi CM3+ SDA0 & SCL0 not working

Tags: raspbian, compute-module-3, compute-module-development-kit

I'm having slight problems with the CM3+ module...

I've written the `dts` overlay and got SCL1 and SDA1 working fine.
The pins 28 and 29 should be SDA0 and SCL0 respectively, which is confirmed when I type `raspi-gpio get 28,29`.

So it should be set. But whenever I type `i2cdetect 2`, `2` because it's detected under `/dev/i2c-2`, it just goes slow, probably timing out on the pin detects. It goes much slower than `i2cdetect 1`.

I'll provide additional info if needed.

UPDATE:
The BCM numbers for above GPIO numbers are:

```
GPIO-28 - B12
GPIO-29 - B1
```

Comment: Pin numbers on the compute modules are different to the other Pis.  Could you quote Broadcom GPIO numbers which are common to all Pis.

Comment: pins are 28 and 30. Above 29 becomes 30 and that's it.

Comment: I have already said pin numbers are meaningless.  Could you edit your question and use Broadcom GPIO numbers?

Comment: @joan I'm sorry, but I thought those were the ones, as they differ from the ones listed in the `raspi-gpio` where could I get those pin numbers?

Comment: @joan I think I found the information you were looking for. I've added it to the OP

Comment: Weird, I would've been quite sure that SDA0 and SCL0 are on BCM Pins 0 and 1. That's also what https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin27_gpio0# suggests. (On the RPI3, these are the HAT eprom pins, but when no HAT is used, they're free for other purposes)

Comment: @PMF yes, SDA0 and SCL0 are on pins 0 and 1, but they're also on 28 and 29, and we can't use pins 0 and 1, because we're using a DPI display on the bank0. I've also solved the issue by upgrading the kernel to 5.4.45 and it suddenly found i2c-0, i2c-1, i2c-2, i2c-10 and i2c-11, where 1, 11 and 2 are HW ones and 0 and 10 are "i2c-11-mux"